# Change font in GRUB with SecureBoot

Tags: grub2, fonts, secure-boot

I have a dual-boot system using Grub. Setting GRUB_FONT seems to be broken by SecureBoot. You can even try the `loadfont` command in Grub's console: it will return an error complaining about SecureBoot.

Is there any solution to this problem? If the font file has to be signed somehow, how can I do that?

Note that I am using Ubuntu 23.10 but I don't think it matters.

Comment: maybe somehow related to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/622313/signing-grub-for-secureboot-uefi-secureboot-forbids-to-load-module-memdisk-bo